# How to diagnose Software Updater issue? It just pops up a window with no content

Tags: update-manager

I have apparently klutzed something on my system as now when I run "Software Updater" all I get is a window with the title "Software Updater" but the window itself has no contents.

Is there a link somewhere to what the GUI should be doing, so I can run the commands from the command line and see which one is failing and then ask a more sane question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulate what GUI does in your terminal and look for error messages:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: That helped some what.  I was able to do those two steps and there was some manual interaction required, where I needed to tell it to take the new script over something locally modified.

However, then I ran it again, and it said there were 67 MB of updates ready to install (already downloaded) so I clicked yes, and then back to same window with no contents....

I tried the apt-get update / ugrade again and this time they did nothing.

Comment: Correction, it said I have 67MB of updates to download.  So, I assume that it is attempting to do a download, but after a "yes", it still shows a window with no contents and I see no indication that it is attempting to fetch anything from the network....

Comment: Try `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoclean` then try again.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.